# The Other People Place bass sound

Tags: sound, bass, electronic

I've spent too many time trying to reproduce this kind of smooth and deep bass sound from "It's Your Love" and "Moonlight Rendezvous" from The Other People Place (aka Drexciya...if I'm not making a mistake), but I always miserably fail. All I can do are some kind of inaudible no-punchy-at-all sub bass, very frustrating.

I use Live 9, I mainly tried with Operator and a Korg Prophet 5 vst (I also have a Nord Lead 2x).

I'll be REALLY happy if someone could share some tips and even tell me which bass synth has originaly been used for those two tracks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a typical bassline sequence 303 style,  square wave with the cut off in a low setting and the resonance somewhere in the middle,  after that just sequence the slides to have the intended duration.  I could prolly sequence something for you to see if you want.

Bassline sequencing is an art by it self.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, really appreciate ! Sure I'm interrested if you can show me how you could sequence that bassline on a 303.

Actually, I recently got a TB-03. It's a whole new world for me so I barely started to understand how it works. I try to program it as much as I can with the original 303 mode (instead of the new "step by step" mode), but as it's still really difficult I mainly use it with the Hi-Tom trigger device of my 606. 

Then yeah I totally agree, this is definitly an art by itself :)

Comment: We have very similar setup.  Also there's no reason to program it in the orig mode,  just go step mode.  I used to own a 303 and programming was not very easy!  But you can surely use the 03 for punchy basslines! 
https://soundcloud.com/mp-analog/analog-wednesday-1 check one track i uploaded with these machines plus some others. Sometimes i turn the cutoff down and it creates that punch you like.  Also tb 303 created a whole new genre,  after that many respected brands have produced similar products or kind of clones which produce very similar results.  But i think you're ok with the 03.

Comment: Ill try to transcribe some of the song you posted (or sth similar) and ill upkoad it for you